# Simplest way to create filename with date and time in command line or batch file

Tags: datetime

I need to append date/time to some test log files generated multiple times in a day. Some suggest doing it like:

```
set CUR_YYYY=%date:~10,4%
set CUR_MM=%date:~4,2%
set CUR_DD=%date:~7,2%

set CUR_NN=%time:~3,2%
set CUR_SS=%time:~6,2%
set CUR_MS=%time:~9,2%

set SUBFILENAME=%CUR_YYYY%%CUR_MM%%CUR_DD%-%CUR_HH%%CUR_NN%%CUR_SS%
```

And then concatenate them together but I feel it's just not right. I wonder if there is a better or more concise way of doing it? I imagine there would be a simple solution because the need is quite common.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, data/time formatting is actually a big thing in any programming languages. Just look at the long list of ToString() methods in C# DateTime class, for example, will give you an idea what it is like.

For your particular task, assuming that your locale date using "-" and your locale time using ":" as separators (you can echo date/time to verify:)

```
echo %date% %time%
```

If you are not picky, the simplest way to generate a file name is below, and you may replace the '-' and ':' characters according to your own locale, which will give you a valid file name in most systems.

```
echo "testResult_%date:-=%_%time::=%.xml"
```

> "testResult_20220409_ 84841.28.xml"

If you want only alphanumeric characters in your naming, then probably a cleaner set of commands:

```
set shortTime=%time:~0,8%                     ##eliminate the milliseconds in time string
set shortTime=%shortTime: =0%                 ##replace empty space with zero in morning hours
echo testResult_%date:-=%_%shortTime::=%.xml  ##replace '-' and ':' with nothing
```

That should give you something like

> testResult_20220409_084841.xml

However, if you need to deal with application globalization, it's always best to format date/time to a predefined string format using something like PowerShell (on Windows) as the first step. It will then make any subsequent string manipulations easier.

```
powershell get-date -format "{dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:ss}"
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with timestamps you can retrieve the date as I show here on this demo shell file (using bash):

```
#!/bin/bash

#gets the current timestamp
current_time=$(date "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
echo "Current Time : $current_time"

#crafts the new filename appending $current_time to the original filename
original_filename="filename.log"
new_fileName=$original_filename.$current_time
echo "New FileName: " "$new_fileName"

#renames the file
#mv $original_filename $new_fileName
```